# Angular 2 why aren't my 4 api calls waiting for the previous call to finish before executing?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-promise, typescript2.0, angular-observable

I have a `form`/`component` that has to do 4 separate API calls in order to do a "save". Really, only one of those transactions needs to wait for the other 3, but I wanted to chain all 4 of them anyway just to be safe.

Here's how I have it setup:

```
save() {
    this.save1(saveObject1)
        .subscribe(response => {
            if (response === 0) {
                this.processErrorResult('save1');
            }

            this.save2(saveObject2)
                .subscribe(response2 => {
                    if (response2 === 0) {
                        this.processErrorResult('save1');
                    }

                    this.save3(saveObject3)
                        .subscribe(response3 => {
                            if (response3 === 0) {
                                this.processErrorResult('save1');
                            }

                            if (this.noErrorsInFirst3Saves()) {
                                this.save4(saveObject4)
                                    .subscribe(response4 => {
                                        if (response4 === 0) {
                                            this.processErrorResult('save1');
                                        }

                                        if (!this.hasErrors()) {
                                            this.router.navigate(['confirmation']);
                                        }
                                    });
                            }
                        });
                });
        });
}

private save1(saveObject: any): Observable<int> {
    this.api.save1(saveObject)
        .subscribe(successful => {
            return Observable.of(1);
        }, failed => {
            return Observable.of(0);
        });
}

private save2(saveObject: any): Observable<int> {
    this.api.save2(saveObject)
        .subscribe(successful => {
            return Observable.of(1);
        }, failed => {
            return Observable.of(0);
        });
}

private save3(saveObject: any): Observable<int> {
    this.api.save3(saveObject)
        .subscribe(successful => {
            return Observable.of(1);
        }, failed => {
            return Observable.of(0);
        });
}

private save4(saveObject: any): Observable<int> {
    this.api.save4(saveObject)
        .subscribe(successful => {
            return Observable.of(1);
        }, failed => {
            return Observable.of(0);
        });
}
```

Inside each of those `save{number}` functions I have log messages so I know exactly the order that these functions get executed (and responses come back).

When I click save, it [almost] immediately redirects to my confirmation page, then I can sit there and watch my console window in chrome dev tools, and see the responses from the API calls start to come in.

Why is this setup not accepting the explicit chaining of these transactions? I know in `Angular` 1, it was very easy to do this with the `promise`, and doing a `.then(response => {});`.

The only thing that I can think of that is different, is for EVERY API call, whether it's a `get`/`post`/`put`/`delete`, it always shows 2 calls in the network panel of chrome dev tools. The first call has the `RequestMethod` set to `Options`, while the subsequent call is the corresponding `get`/`post`/`put`/`delete` with the `RequestMethod` set accordingly.

I don't remember ever seeing those (duplicated calls) in any of my recent applications I've worked on, (maybe I just never paid attention as much) so maybe that's just the standard-operating-procedure for API calls.

Any ideas here?

**Edit:** In response to Harry's suggested answer below

I'm trying to implement your answer, but still a little confused on how to implement, here's a closer look at my setup:

```
private save1(saveObject: any): Observable<number> {
    if (saveObject.hasChanges()) {
        return this.api.save1(saveObject)
            .map(successful => {
                return this.parseSaveResponse(successful, saveObject, true); // true indicates a successful API response
            })
            .catch(failed => {
                return this.parseSaveResponse(successful, saveObject, false); // false indicates a successful API response
            });
    } else {
        return Observable.of(-1); // no changes necessary, return immediately
    }
}

private parseSaveResponse(response: any, saveObject: any, transactionSuccessful: boolean) {
    this.logService.logTransaction({transactionType}, saveObject, response, transactionSuccessful);

    if (!transactionSuccessful) {
        // add to error list object to be displayed on the form
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

When getting it to this point, it's throwing me an error on the `.catch({});` line saying:

> Argument of type '(error: any) => 0 | 1' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<0 | 1>) =>
>   ObservableInput<{}>'.   Type '0 | 1' is not assignable to type
>   'ObservableInput<{}>'.
>       Type '0' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.)

Comment: look into the switchmap transformation operator in rxjs to chain your calls. It can take an Observable as input and you can use that to call your other api. If you want to wait you could look into Observable.forkJoin method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres quite a few issues with your code which might be contributing. Firstly your save1/save2/save3 methods should just return the observable from your API which you will be able to subscribe to.

Secondly you're using the **int** type which doesn't exist in Typescript. Use **number**.

```
private save1(saveObject: any): Observable<number> {
  return this.api.save1(saveObject);
}
// or
private save1(saveObject: any): Observable<number> {
  return this.api.save1(saveObject).map(response => 1).catch(response => 0)
}
```

If you wanted to modify the items emitted you could add the map operator which maps the item emitted to something else.

Lastly you should avoid subscribing to an observable from within an observable. You can chain observables together using the **flatMap** operator. This transforms the items emitted by an Observable into Observables, then flatten the emissions from those into a single Observable.

```
save() {
  this.save1(saveObject1)
    .flatMap(response1 => this.save2(saveObject2))
    .flatMap(response2 => {
      if (response2 === 0) {
        // handle error
      }
      return this.save3(saveObject3);
    })
    .flatMap(() => this.save4(saveObject4))
    .subscribe(response4 => {
      // do redirect
    });
  }
```

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html

Comment: sorry, they are returning Observable<number> already, that was just a pseudo-code write-up and forgetting I was in the typescript world instead of C#. I'll read through the rest of your response...

Comment: I believe I have gotten it work....once I confirm with some more testing, I'll update my question to have the working version, and I'll award you your answer points. Thanks [I think]...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to "return" your observables. Ex:

Change this:

```
this.api.save1(saveObject)
```

To:

```
return this.api.save1(saveObject)
```

Comment: even though each of those `this.api.save1()` calls have a `.subscribe`, and in that they are doing `return Observable.of({number});`?

Comment: @ganders yes. you need both returns

Comment: as soon as I add the return where you stated, vscode throws the red error line under that whole block saying: `type subscription is not assignable to type Observable<number>`

Comment: return 1 instead of Observable.of(1)? not sure from here

Comment: Tried that, didn't change the error. If I remove the "`: Observable<int> {` from this line: `private save1(saveObject: any): Observable<int> {`, then it clears the error there, but then in shows an error in the save function saying `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription | Observable<number>'`